# Add days to date ranges that have to start with Monday

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am working on a time slot generation feature in which I have to generate a from-date and a to-date of the current year. The duration of the time slot will be inserted in a textbox.

Here I have made a time slot in the current year but I need all from-dates to start on Monday only.

So, if a slot starts on Friday, then skip the days until Monday.

Here I have done it without starting on Monday:

```
string fdate = "01/01/" + System.DateTime.Today.Year;
fdate = Convert.ToDateTime(fdate).AddDays(-1).ToString();
string ffdate = "";
string ttdate = "";
for (int date = 0; date < 365; )
{
    ffdate += Convert.ToDateTime(fdate).AddDays(1 + date).ToString() + ",";
    date += Convert.ToInt32(txtTime.Text);
    ttdate += Convert.ToDateTime(fdate).AddDays(date).ToString() + ",";
}
fromdate = ffdate.TrimEnd(',');
todate = ttdate.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: Your question - if any - is not clear. You should rephrase...

Comment: @Purvaesh See C# TimeSpan class i used it for a timetable project. It is very helpful then using string and/or datetime

Comment: you need start dates falling on a `Monday` ? then what about the end dates and what is the time slot you want to calculate like in days or hours, please add the relevant bits

Comment: yes i need only from dates to start with monday and todayes are fallen respectively as fromdates and time slot is given in days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but judging from your comment, this may be useful.

If the from-date is given in days (starting from the beginning of the year), you can calculate the from-date by doing:

```
// minus one if entering 1 in the textbox means 1st of January. 
// Remove if 1st of January would require the user to enter 0
var daysToAdd = (int)textBoxFrom.Text - 1;
var fromDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1).AddDays(daysToAdd);
// you could also do: new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, (int)textBoxFrom.Text)
```

Now, find the first Monday:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (fromDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(i);
    }
}
```

And finally, calculate the to-date:

```
var toDate = fromDate.AddDays((int)textBoxDays.Text);
```

Now you have your dates and can convert them to string if necessary. Also, you might want to check out [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx). I've just cast the content of the textboxes, assuming a correct integer was entered. But maybe the user can enter letters, which would give you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int day= 31; 
int month = 12;
bool IsMonday =false;
string fdate = day.Tostring() + "/"+month.Tostring()+ "/" + System.DateTime.Today.Year;
while(IsMonday )
{   

    if(DayOfWeek.Monday == (DateTime.ParseExact(fdate , "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).DayOfWeek) {
        IsMonday = true;
    } else {
        if(day==31){
            day= 1;
            month =1;
        } else {
            day= day+1;
            month =1;
        }
        fdate = day.Tostring() + "/"+month.Tostring()+ "/" + System.DateTime.Today.Year;
    }
}
string ffdate = "";
string ttdate = "";
for (int date = 0; date < 365; date=date+7 ){
    ffdate += Convert.ToDateTime(fdate).AddDays(date).ToString() + ",";        
    ttdate += Convert.ToDateTime(fdate).AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(txtTime.Text)).ToString() + ",";
}
fromdate = ffdate.TrimEnd(',');
todate = ttdate.TrimEnd(',');
```